# Compulsion on the Great Captains

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the "A Memory of Light" it turns out somewhere near the end, that all four great captains were under Compulsion, I think placed on them by Graendal/Hessalam.

Do we know when this started? Was this in effect since the very beginning of the book?

Comment: the compulsion on them started when the last battle starts, perrin sees this right away while in tel aran rhiod.

Comment: Perrin sees it being done, but that is not a clear indication, that that is when it started.

Comment: @Himarm Well, Rodel Ituralde did have that brief encounter with Lady Basene/Graendal way back in LoC, and I always assumed Rahvin probably at least tried to control Gareth Bryne through compulsion before banishing him. But then again, neither of those examples have anything to do with the last battle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never specifically stated but I took it that it began at the start of the Last Battle. Specifically after Graendal had failed in earlier attempts to kill Perrin and was given a new task by Moridin or Shaidar Haran or whoever it was. We can surmise this because Rodel had not been under compulsion when he held Maradon against the Shadow in the book prior.